# Writing data in spreadsheet in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a map(key, value) pair to google sheets using app script.
I have tried using the method below

```
var crNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("newWorksheetName",1,1);
var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(crNew.getUrl());

var x=ssNew.getRange("A1");
x.setValues(apimap.keys,apimap.values);
```

but I'm getting an error as follows

> Exception: The parameters (String,String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.
> myfunction  @ Code.gs:102

Can anyone please tell that where i'm doing wrong.The line 102 is this one x.setValues(apimap.keys,apimap.values);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved my task as follows (posting it here in case someone faces it in future):

```
   var crNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("newWorksheetName",1,1);
    var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(crNew.getUrl());
   
    
    var a=[];
    apimap.forEach (function(value, key) {    //apimap is my map containing data
      a.push([key,value]);    //i pushed data map into an array
    })
    var x=ssNew.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(1,1,a.length,a[0].length);
    x.setValues(a);
```

This automatically writes keys in one column and values in the adjacent column

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call `setValues` method with 2 arguments.

Based on [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) this method waits for a two-dimensional array of values as an argument:
[image]